# Powershell web request without throwing exception on 4xx/5xx

Tags: powershell

I'm writing a powershell script that needs to make a web request and inspect the status code of the response.

I have tried writing this:

```
$client = new-object system.net.webclient

$response = $client.DownloadData($url)
```

as well as this:

```
$response = Invoke-WebRequest $url
```

but whenever the web page has a status code that's not a success status code, PowerShell goes ahead and throws an exception instead of giving me the actual response object.

How can I get the status code of the page even when it fails to load?

Comment: This worked for me https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-6   Example 7: Catch non success messages from Invoke-WebRequest

Answer (score 148, accepted):

Try this:

```
try { $response = Invoke-WebRequest http://localhost/foo } catch {
      $_.Exception.Response.StatusCode.Value__}
```

It is kind of a bummer that this throws an exception but that's the way it is.

### Update per comments

To ensure that such errors still return a valid response, you can capture those exceptions of type `WebException` and fetch the related `Response`.

Since the response on the exception is of type `System.Net.HttpWebResponse`, whilst the response from a successful `Invoke-WebRequest` call is of type `Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.HtmlWebResponseObject`, to return a compatible type from both scenarios we need to take the successful response's `BaseResponse`, which is also of type `System.Net.HttpWebResponse`.

This new response type's status code is an enum of type `[system.net.httpstatuscode]`, rather than a simple integer, so you have to explicity convert it to int, or access its `Value__` property as described above to get the numeric code.

```
#ensure we get a response even if an error's returned
$response = try { 
    (Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'localhost/foo' -ErrorAction Stop).BaseResponse
} catch [System.Net.WebException] { 
    Write-Verbose "An exception was caught: $($_.Exception.Message)"
    $_.Exception.Response 
} 

#then convert the status code enum to int by doing this
$statusCodeInt = [int]$response.BaseResponse.StatusCode
#or this
$statusCodeInt = $response.BaseResponse.StatusCode.Value__
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked.  I didn't realize that you could just access the Response object from the Exception object.

Comment: Yeah, getting to the actual code number was a bit tricky.  :-)

Comment: My go to is using this code from Chris Wahl, http://wahlnetwork.com/2015/02/19/using-try-catch-powershells-invoke-webrequest/

Comment: A slightly better way:

$response = try { Invoke-WebRequest http://localhost/foo } catch {
      $_.Exception.Response }

That way you get something in the $response variable in both cases.  But be aware that a failure returns an HtmlWebResponse, but a success returns an HtmlWebResponseObject.  In particular, the StatusCode on those are different types (sigh..)

Comment: But how do you get response content in this case?

Comment: Passing `-ErrorVariable ErrorBody` (no `$`) as an argument to `Invoke-WebRequest` will cause the response content to be stored in a variable with that name, `$ErrorBody` in this case. That variable can be used to access that content in the catch block. If `Invoke-WebRequest` is successful, that error variable will be empty.

Comment: A couple of minor tweaks to Rob's great suggestion, to avoid the issue with different types: `$response = try { (Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'localhost/foo' -ErrorAction Stop).BaseRequest  } catch [System.Net.WebException] { $_.Exception.Response }`.  I.e. fetching `BaseRequest` ensures that in both success and error scenarios we're getting an `HttpWebReqponse`.  Adding `[System.Net.WebException]` ensures we only capture relevant exceptions in this way / don't accidentally sweep up other types of issues.

Comment: @JohnLBevan - I think your comment is useful enough to post it as an additional answer, especially with some of the other info in these comments about the different response types.

Comment: Thanks @Taegost. I don't feel my comment is different from the accepted answer; it just adds some more info, so I've edited Keith's existing answer to include this info so people can see it without delving into the comments.

Comment: @RobCannon It's not so bad. All you need to do to accomodate the different values of StatusCode is to cast to enum before casting to int. `[int] [System.Net.HttpStatusCode] $StatusCode = 'OK'  # Or 200`

Comment: @AndrewSavinykh Something like this `$Content, $StatusCode = try { $Response = Invoke-WebRequest @searchParams; $Response.Content; $Response.StatusCode } catch [System.Net.WebException] { $Response = $_.Exception.Response; try { $Stream = $Response.GetResponseStream(); $Encoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding($Response.CharacterSet); $Reader = [System.IO.StreamReader]::new($Stream, $Encoding); $Reader.DiscardBufferedData(); $Reader.ReadToEnd(); } finally { $Reader.Close(); } $Response.StatusCode.value__; }`

Answer (score 36):

Since Powershell version 7.0 `Invoke-WebRequest` have `-SkipHttpErrorCheck` switch parameter.

> **-SkipHttpErrorCheck**
>
> This parameter causes the cmdlet to ignore HTTP error statuses and
> continue to process responses. The error responses are written to the
> pipeline just as if they were successful.
>
> This parameter was introduced in PowerShell 7.

[docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-7.3#-skiphttperrorcheck) [pull request](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/pull/10466)

Comment: Oh you magnificent! My mind went on berserk trying to find a solution and it was this one.

Comment: Also on `Invoke-RestMethod`

Answer (score 7):

`-SkipHttpErrorCheck` is the best solution for PowerShell 7+, but if you can't use that yet then here is a simple alternative that is useful for interactive, command-line Poweshell sessions.

When you see the an error description for a 404 response, i.e.,

> The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.

Then you can see the 'last error' from the command-line by entering this:

```
$Error[0].Exception.Response.StatusCode
```

Or

```
$Error[0].Exception.Response.StatusDescription
```

Or whatever else you would like to know from the `Response’ object.