# Download a file, get the status, then execute the file

Tags: powershell, powershell-7.0

I've tried `invoke-restmethod`, `new-object` and many other methods to achieve what I'm trying to do. Here are the latest two iterations:

```
$req = Invoke-WebRequest -uri $scripturl -OutFile "$($scriptpath)\fls.core.ps1" 
Write-Host "StatusCode:" $req.StatusCode

$req = Invoke-WebRequest -uri $scripturl -OutFile "$($scriptpath)\fls.core.ps1" | Select-Object -Expand StatusCode
Write-Host "StatusCode:" $req
```

Basically I'm attempting to download another PowerShell script and execute it.  So obviously it needs to be synchronous. I also need the status so I can determine if it updated or not.

Here is pseudo code for what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
try {
    download file
} catch {
    output error
    if (local copy exists) {
        log warning that local copy is being used
    } else {
        log error could not download and no local copy available
        exit script
    }
}

run script (only after downloading new one if available)
```

Here is my current code in full:

```
$param1=$args[0]
if ($param1 -eq "-d" -or $param1 -eq "-D") { 
    $isDev = $true 
}

#todo: Move to config file
$logpath = "c:\company\logs\loginscript"
$scriptpath = "c:\company\scripts\"
$scripturl = "http://downloads.company.com/fls.core.ps1"
$logfile="$(Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd hhmmss").log"

Function log($message) {
    Write-Output "[$(Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd hhmmss")] $message" | Out-file "$($logpath)\$($logfile)" -append
    if ($isDev) { Write-Host "[$(Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd hhmmss")] $message" }
}

Function createFolder($path) {
    if (-!(Test-Path $path)) { New-Item -Type Directory -Path $path }
}


function updateScripts() {
    try {
        $req = Invoke-WebRequest -uri $scripturl -OutFile "$($scriptpath)\fls.core.ps1" 
        Write-Host "StatusCode:" $req.StatusCode
    } catch {
        Write-Host "StatusCode:" $req.StatusCode
        if ($req.StatusCode -eq 404) {
            log "WARNING: Script not found at $scripturl"
        } else {
            log "ERROR: Script download error: $req.StatusCode"
        }
        if (Test-Path "$($scriptpath)\fls.core.ps1") {
            log "WARNING: Using local script"
        } else {
            log "ERROR: Unable to update script and no local script found. Exiting."
            exit
        }
    }
}

#----------------------------------------------#
#---- MAIN CODE BLOCK -------------------------#
#----------------------------------------------#

createFolder $logpath
createFolder $scriptpath

#update scripts
updateScripts
#execute core loginscript
& $scriptpath/fls.core.ps1
```

`$req.StatusCode` appears to be null.

Comment: I previously had this working using `New-Object -TypeName System.IO.FileStream -ArgumentList $targetFile, Create` only it would execute the script before it finished downloading the new update (or try to execute a script that didn't exist)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[`Invoke-WebRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest) reports errors as *statement-terminating* errors**, which means that *no assignment to variable `$req`* (in statement `$req = Invoke-WebRequest ...`) takes place in case an error occurs.

Update:

- In **[*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md)**, you can now use the **`-SkipHttpErrorCheck`** switch to suppress the error and get a response object back as usual, whose `.StatusCode` property contains the HTTP status code; e.g.:

  ```
  # PS 7+ only: -> 404
  (Invoke-WebRequest -SkipHttpErrorCheck http://example.org/nosuchpage).StatusCode
  ```
- The **following applies to *Windows PowerShell*** (but the technique still works in PowerShell (Core)).

Instead, unfortunately, **if an error occurs, the response object<sup>[1]</sup> must be gleaned from the [`[ErrorRecord]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord) instance representing the error**, which is available via `$Error[0]` after the fact, or via `$_` in the `catch` block of a `try { ... } catch { ... }` statement (adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19122582/45375)):

```
try {
  Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $scripturl -OutFile "$scriptpath\fls.core.ps1"
} catch [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.HttpResponseException] {
  # Get the status code...
  $statuscode = $_.Exception.Response.StatusCode
  # ... and work with it.
  # if ($statusCode -eq 404) { ...
} catch {
  # Unexpected error, re-throw
  throw
}
```

<sup>Strictly speaking, `$_.Exception.Response.StatusCode` returns a value from an *enumeration* type, [`System.Net.HttpStatusCode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Net.HttpStatusCode), not an `[int]` value, but you can use it like an integer. To return an integer to begin with, append `.Value__` or cast to `[int]`.</sup>

Note that `Invoke-WebRequest` is always *synchronous*; if you download a file (successfully), the call won't return until the download is completed.

---

<sup>[1] As the linked answer explains, the response object contained in the error record is of a *different type* than the one that `Invoke-WebRequest` returns in case of success (which requires `-PassThru` if `-OutFile` is also specified): The error record's `.Exception.Response` property contains a [`System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage) instance, whereas `Invoke-WebRequest` returns an instance (derived from) [`Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebResponseObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebResponseObject), which *incorporates* an instance of the former type, in its `.BaseResponse` property.</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the thorough response. Very helpful. Also, it turns out it *was* working in a previous iteration (due to dumb luck), I just forgot I had added a `$isDev` check to my core script which is why I wasn't seeing output in the console.  This is what happens when IT Management writes code :)