# Powershell webrequest handle response code and exit

Tags: powershell, http-status-codes, invoke-webrequest

I want it to exit when the response status code is 429, how can I do it? my looped ps1 script
I don't want to use do or try or catch methods. Is there a simple method? this is my code and i want it to exit when response code 429

```
'header' = 'header'}
"@
$req = @{
    Uri         = 'https://mywebsite.com/api/'
    Headers     = $headers
    Method      = 'get'
    ContentType = 'application/json'}
while($true){
Invoke-WebRequest @req
status code 429 = exit}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Caveat**: Given that your code makes ongoing requests in a tight loop, it should only be run against a *test* web service / site.

> I don't want to use do or try or catch methods.

In ***Windows PowerShell***, you ***must* use `try` / `catch`**:

```
while (
 429 -ne 
 $(try { $null=Invoke-WebRequest @req } catch { $_.Exception.Response.StatusCode })
) { }
```

In **[*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md)**, you can use the **`-SkipHttpErrorCheck`** switch:

```
while (429 -ne (Invoke-WebRequest -SkipHttpErrorCheck @req).StatusCode) { }
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69501633/45375) for details.